# sql query search into two tables, performance issue

Tags: sql, sqlperformance, qsqlquery

I have two tables (I'll list only fields that I want to search)

MySQL version: 5.0.96-community

```
Table 1: Clients (860 rows)
ID_CLIENT (varcahar 10)
ClientName (text)

Table 2: Details (22380 rows)
ID_CLIENT (varchar 10)
Details (varchar 1000)
```

The `Details` table can have multiple rows from the same client.

I need to search into those two tables and retrive the ids of clients that match a search value.

If i have a search value "blue" it has to match `CLientName` (ex the `Blue`berries Corp), or  the `Details` in the second table (ex "it has a `blue` logo)

The result should be a list of client id's that match the criteria.

If I make a query for one table, it takes a decent time

```
#0.002 sec
select a.`ID_CLIENT` from clienti a
where 
a.`ClientName` LIKE '%blue%' 


#0.1 sec
SELECT b.`ID_CLIENT` FROM Details b
WHERE b.`Details` LIKE  '%blue%'
GROUP BY b.`GUID_CLIENT`
```

But if I try to join those two queries it takes ages.

My questions(s)

1. What's the best way of doing what I need here, to get a list of ID-s based on the search result from both tables
2. What to change to improve search performance in the Details table, I know that %..% is not fast, but I need partial matches too.

Edit (based on the answers)

```
#~0.2 sec
(SELECT a.`ID_CLIENT` FROM `clienti` a  where a.`ClientName` like '%blue%')  
union
(SELECT distinct b.`ID_CLIENT` FROM `Details` b where b.`Details` like '%blue%')
```

It returns a list of IDs from both tables filtred by the search value.

Edit 2: final query

And with that list of ids I can filter the client table, to get only the clients that are in boths tables based on their id

```
select cl.`ID_CLIENT`, `ClientName`, `OtherField`
from clients cl 
join 
((SELECT a.`ID_CLIENT` FROM `clients` a  where a.`ClientName` like '%blue%')
union
(SELECT distinct b.`ID_Client` FROM `Details` b where b.`Detail` like '%blue%' )) rez 
on cl.`ID_CLIENT` = rez.`ID_CLIENT`
```

Comment: The only way that you can speed this type of search is to switch to using a full text index.  This assumes that you are searching for full words.

Comment: Could you post your joined query?

Comment: By the way, it is always useful to mention the RDMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two queries work, just use `union`:

```
select a.`ID_CLIENT`
from clienti a
where  a.`ClientName` LIKE '%blue%' 
union
SELECT b.`ID_CLIENT`
FROM Details b
WHERE b.`Details` LIKE '%blue%';
```

The `union` will remove all duplicates, so you don't need a separate `group by` query.

Why are the two search strings different for the two tables?  The question suggests searching for `blue` in both of them.

If the individual queries don't perform well, you might need to switch to a full text index.

Comment: The original query is not in english, I changed it to be more "readable".

Answer (score 1):

If both queries are functioning as you wish, simply union the results together.  This is much faster than 'or' on a query that cannot effectively use indexes and it will also allow you to remove duplicates in the same statement.

Answer (score 1):

Divide et impera: create two subqueries.

In the first subquery, left join Clients with Details based on client_id, filtering on row values where clientname like '%xxxxx%'

Then another subquery, left joining details with clients ( but keep the same order of fields in output projection), filtering on details text field. Then create a union query from the two subqueries, and finally create a select distinct * from this union

Final schema:

Select distinct * from (subquery1 union subquery2)

This seems to be a really slow and silly "manual query plan optimization", just give a try and let we know of it works!